# RedirectToAction between areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, redirecttoaction

Is there a way to redirect to a specific action/controller on a different Area?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Did you try this?:

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "area" });
```

Comment: I am not seeing this work when I go from an area back to the main app.  Area=""??

Comment: @MvcCMsJon `return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "" });` should do it.

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users", new { area = "Administration" });` is giving `No route matches the supplied values.`

Answer (score 57):

Your answer was helpful to me. Just wanted to add below:

If you want to redirect from one area to another area, above code works well.

And, if you want to redirect from one area to a controller/view which is not there in the area folder (i.e. in most cases, your front end), you can specify area = "".

i.e.

```
return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "AreaName/ControllerName");
```