# Returning view from within an Area, results in different view being displayed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I run the website, I'm expecting the `Home` view to be displayed but its not finding the view. If i alter the code below, and remove the `.mvc` from `("{controller}.mvc/{action}"` I get the base index view, not the Home view i wish to get from the Home Area.

What I noticed after I removed `.mvc` from the Route - The `Home` controller located inside `Areas-Home-Controllers-HomeController` is being found and executed, when the view gets returned and the `AreaViewEngine` takes ahold of it, it doesn't see the Areas so it returns base index view... Any clue what could be causing this!?

**I have the following `RegisterRoutes`**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapAreas("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        "ProjectNamespace.Web",
        new[] { "Home" });

    routes.MapRootArea("{controller}.mvc/{action}",
        "ProjectNamespace.Web",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

**Here is `ViewFind` located in `AreaViewEngine.cs`:**

```
   public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            ViewEngineResult areaResult = null;

            if (controllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("area")) 
            {
                string areaViewName = FormatViewName(controllerContext, viewName);
                areaResult = base.FindView(controllerContext, areaViewName, masterName, useCache);
                if (areaResult != null && areaResult.View != null) 
                {
                    return areaResult;
                }
                string sharedAreaViewName = FormatSharedViewName(controllerContext, viewName);
                areaResult = base.FindView(controllerContext, sharedAreaViewName, masterName, useCache);
                if (areaResult != null && areaResult.View != null) 
                {
                    return areaResult;
                }
            }
            return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
        }
```

**The `BaseController` which is located in the default Controllers root directory:**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Here is the `Home` controller located in `Areas-Home-Controllers`:**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public override ActionResult Index()
    {           
        HomeDetailsViewModel model = new HomeDetailsViewModel();
        model.User = "testing username"
        return View("Index", model);
    }
 }
```

**Finally, screenshot of the Solutions Explorer:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for an area you have to specify it.  try this

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Home" });
```

Comment: Its not working for me, "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" - I should have mentioned that `HomeController` also implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I just searched and my answer should be working for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391887/redirecttoaction-between-areas.  Home is a reserved word that mvc uses as a default.  Since it is in an area I would recommend changing that name to something else.  See if that helps