# Same Controller Name in different namespaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have my file structure setup as:

```
Controllers/Requestor/RequestorHomeController (Namespace: Proj.Presentation.Controllers.Requestor)
Controllers/Approver/ApproverHomeController (Namespace: Proj.Presentation.Controllers.Approver)
```

My routes look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PrependRequestor",
            url: "requestor/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RequestorHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Proj.Presentation.Controllers.Requestor" }
        );
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PrependApprover",
            url: "approver/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ApproverHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Proj.Presentation.Controllers.Approver" }
        );
```

I am not receiving any errors, but when I go to `Approver/ApproverHomeController/Index` the first route is being hit because the url is `requestor/approverhome`.  If it is in a different namespace, shouldn't that first controller be ignored?  Any suggestions on what I can do to hit the second route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route

```
Approver/ApproverHomeController/Index
```

does not work because you must omit the "Controller" in the url.

It will work as

```
Approver/ApproverHome/Index
```

You also must get to the second route with

```
approver
```

because you have default values for the controller and action parts.

**Update:**

If you want to make a redirect from a controller in a different namespace you should use

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "approverhome", new { area = "approver" } );
```

Comment: So the URL should look like `requestor/{action}/{id}` and `approver/{action}/{id}`?

Comment: no, requestor/{controller name without the "controller" part}/{action}/{id}   edited the answer to clarify...

Comment: I'm sorry, either I'm not understanding you correctly or that isn't working.  Could you type the full `routes.MapRoute` in your answer to make sure it's what I have now.

Comment: I'm not actually typing in "Approver/ApproverHomeController/Index".  I have a `RedirectToAction("index", "approverhome")` and that is making the url look like `requestor/approverhome`.

Comment: In that case i think your problem is that you must specify the area in your RedirectToAction. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391887/redirecttoaction-between-areas)